# Another apache rewrite question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my scenario I redirect 
"/index/../" to "/index.php?act=..".
 
I was wondering how can I restrict direct access to "/index.php" but still be able to redirect from "/index/../"?

P.S. "/../" is anything... it seems you can't use * there. O.o

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your rewrite script
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php$ [NC]`. This rule will fail for `/index.php` (but not `/index.php?whatever`). At least I think it will, I haven't tested it.

Comment: That doesn't work with me. I don't know hwy but it's not stopping from direct access.